# Using apply to loop over different datasets in a regression

Tags: r, apply, lm

I found this way of looping over variables in an lm() when the variable names are stored as characters (http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/pages/looping_strings.htm):

```
models <- lapply(varlist, function(x) {
    lm(substitute(read ~ i, list(i = as.name(x))), data = hsb2)
})
```

My first question is: Is there a more efficient/faster way?

What if I want to loop over different data instead of looping over variables?

Example:

```
reg1 <- lm(a~b, data=dataset1)
reg2 <- lm(a~b, data=dataset2)
```

Can I apply something similar to the code shown above? Using the substitute function for the data did not work.

Thank You!

Comment: Do you need to change the formula in the lm `Call` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `substitute` in your example is used to construct the formula. If you want to to apply `lm` to a number of `data.frame`s use:

```
lapply(list(dataset1, dataset2), lm, formula = a ~ b)
```

Comment: That is exactly what i needed! Do you also know how I can replace the data used in a for-loop?

Comment: Can you give a example?